# Lexicographically Smallest String

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, algorithm-analysis, string-manipulation

**Problem Statement**: Given a string/pattern only consisting of **'<'** and **'>'** symbol, find the **lexicographically** smallest string that satisfies the pattern(made up of only lowercase english alphabets). Some examples are given below for better understanding.

**Examples**:

1. *Input*(String) - '**>>**'
   *Output*(String) - '**cba**' (because c > b > a)
2. *Input*(String) - '**>**'
   *Output*(String) - '**ba**' (because b > a)
3. *Input*(String) - '**><>**'
   *Output*(String) - '**badc**' (because b > a < d > c)

**Constraints**: String/Pattern length is always <= 25 and in the output string, no alphabet should be repeated.

I am unable to come up with any approach which has a lesser complexity than **O(N!)**(which would surely never pass the time limits), N being the given string/pattern's length. Any help is appreciated.

**P.S.** - This problem was asked in a HackerEarth hiring contest, and no, the contest is no longer live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote the solution for a string $w$ and a set $A$ of remaining letters by $s(w,A)$. Also let $A = a_1 < \cdots < a_n$. If $w$ equals $>^{n-1}$ then clearly the solution is $a_n a_{n-1} \ldots a_1$. If $w$ starts with a run of $\ell$ many $>$'s (possibly $\ell=0$), then the first $\ell+1$ letters of any solution must be $a_{\ell+1} \ldots a_1$ or lexicographically larger. Conversely, there always is such a solution – we can construct one recursively. This shows that
$$
 s(>^\ell<x,\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\})=a_{\ell+1}\ldots a_1 s(x,\{a_{\ell+2},\ldots,a_n\}), \quad s(>^{n-1},\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}) = a_n \ldots a_1.
$$
Since this greedy construction always "eats away" a prefix of the alphabet, it can easily be implemented in linear time.